# Convert list of list into a tibble

Tags: r, list, tidyverse, tibble

I have read [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45452015/how-to-convert-list-of-list-into-a-tibble-dataframe), and I cannot make sense of it in my case, where I have `ggplot`s in my `tibble`.

Say I have:

```
library(tidyverse)
f <- function(n) {
  p <- tibble(x = rnorm(30, n)) %>%
    ggplot(aes(x = x)) + geom_density()
  return(list(n = n, p = p))
}
m <- map(seq(10), f)
```

I would like to turn `m` into a `tibble`, with ten rows and two columns, named `n` and `p`.
I also would like my code to work with any number of columns, any type of column, if possible.

`as_tibble(transpose(m))`
gives me

```
# A tibble: 10 x 2
   n         p     
   <list>    <list>
 1 <int [1]> <gg>  
 2 <int [1]> <gg>  
 3 <int [1]> <gg>  
 ...
```

*i.e.* each cell is a list, with one element.
I would like to transform each list to a scalar.

What I have tried:

- I have used `map_int` for the column `n`, but what to do with column `p`?
- `unnest` also work for column `n`, but not with `p`.
- Same with `unlist` on the column `p` (even with `recursive = FALSE`).

Comment: Keeping your function as it is `tibble(n = seq_len(n), 
       p = map(n, f))` works as well, where `n = 10` ?

Comment: @RonakShah: Well, I would like to use the output of `f` as `n`.  I admit the example is probably over-simplified.

Answer (score 1):

Here is one possibility.
You modify the function such that it only returns the plot. Then you create the tibble with only column `n` and create column `p` using `map`.

```
f2 <- function(n) {
  tibble(x = rnorm(30, n)) %>%
    ggplot(aes(x = x)) + geom_density()
}

tibble(n = 1:10,
       p = map(n, f2))
```

Then column `n` is an integer. `p` is a list but this is the best you can get since columns of tibbles cannot contain objects of type `gg` or `ggplot` but only lists containing these objects.

As far as I know the only possible column types are: `int`, `dbl`, `date`, `dttm`, `factor`, `logical`, `character` and `list`.

Comment: In real life, `f` computes lots of things, so I would not favour this solution.  Could you please add a link to why `tibble`s cannot contain `gg`s?

Comment: Maybe chapter 3.6 of advanced R:
https://adv-r.hadley.nz/vectors-chap.html