# Missing Name in Data-Hierarchy during "bind_rows" from dplyr in Rstudio - Getting Okex Ticker

Tags: r, dplyr

i try to convert the okex-ticker to a dataframe, using dplyr library, which was very successfull on other marketplaces.

Here´s the entire Code:

```
library(dplyr)
library(httr)
GET(
  url = "https://www.okex.com/v2/spot/markets/tickers"
) -> okexRes
x5=content(okexRes)
dfokex <- bind_rows(x5$data)
```

I think there´s something missing in brackets of the last line, like `(x5$data$???)`, but in the environment of RStudio it looks like this

```
x5        Large list
 code : int 0
 data :List of 407
 ..$ :List of 24
 .. .. $ brokerId: int 0
 .. .. $ buy: chr "9314.4"
 .. .. $ change: ...
```

Whats the name(?) of the second list here? Is there a function for showing the names?
Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45452015/how-to-convert-list-of-list-into-a-tibble-dataframe

Comment: There's no name of that list; data is an unnamed list of named lists. I think you're getting at the same problem answered in the post above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One problem that I see here is that the response from that API is containing an empty object under the json-key `"name"`. This looks like `{[...], "name":{}, [...]}` in the ticker.
R is converting that into an empty list - which will then cause an error when you try to coerce the entries of `data` into a dataframe.

What will easily help you with your problem is if you add one step where you `flatten` each entry of `data`, which will convert the list into a dataframe ready for row-binding.

Try this:

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)

dfokex <- x5$data %>%
  lapply(flatten_dfr) %>%
  bind_rows()
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! Working great after adding one line between lapply and bind rows, cause of an error: Column `currencyId` can't be converted from character to integer. To get it work, add:   lapply(., mutate_if, is.integer, as.character) %>%

Comment: Oh sorry for that then. I only tested it on the first bunch of entries so that didn't pop up on my end. Good you figured it out :)